# Invalid BitmapData error when Flex tries to play a Crossfade transition, and I have a mx:Grid with two or more Label elements

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex4, flash-builder

I've got a Grid like this in my Flex 4 app.  When the view that contains this Grid is visible, and the view is changed to another view, my application tries to play the Crossfade effect as the transition to the other view.  My transition is defined like this:

```
 <s:transitions>
      <s:Transition fromState="*" toState="*">
           <s:Parallel>
                <s:CrossFade duration="150" target="{this}" />
           </s:Parallel>
      </s:Transition>
 </s:transitions>
```

This applies the transition to any view.  There's only one effect in there at the moment but it's in a Parallel block since I've experimented with multiple transitions.

Now, when I'm on a view where this Grid is visible, and I try to transition to another view, I get an "Invalid BitmapData" error.  HEre's the complete stack trace:

```
ArgumentError: Error #2015: Invalid BitmapData.
 at flash.display::BitmapData/ctor()
 at flash.display::BitmapData()
 at spark.utils::BitmapUtil$/getRealBounds()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\utils\BitmapUtil.as:99]
 at spark.utils::BitmapUtil$/getRealBounds()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\utils\BitmapUtil.as:135]
 at spark.utils::BitmapUtil$/getRealBounds()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\utils\BitmapUtil.as:135]
 at spark.utils::BitmapUtil$/getRealBounds()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\utils\BitmapUtil.as:135]
 at spark.utils::BitmapUtil$/getRealBounds()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\utils\BitmapUtil.as:135]
 at spark.utils::BitmapUtil$/getRealBounds()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\utils\BitmapUtil.as:135]
 at spark.utils::BitmapUtil$/getRealBounds()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\utils\BitmapUtil.as:135]
 at spark.utils::BitmapUtil$/getRealBounds()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\utils\BitmapUtil.as:135]
 at spark.utils::BitmapUtil$/getRealBounds()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\utils\BitmapUtil.as:135]
 at spark.utils::BitmapUtil$/getSnapshot()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\utils\BitmapUtil.as:63]
 at spark.effects::AnimateTransitionShader/getValueFromTarget()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\effects\AnimateTransitionShader.as:283]
 at mx.effects::Effect/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::captureValues()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\effects\Effect.as:1462]
 at mx.effects::CompositeEffect/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::captureValues()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\effects\CompositeEffect.as:377]
 at mx.effects::CompositeEffect/captureStartValues()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\effects\CompositeEffect.as:358]
 at mx.core::UIComponent/commitCurrentState()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:9778]
 at mx.core::UIComponent/setCurrentState()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:9701]
 at mx.core::UIComponent/set currentState()[E:\dev\4.0.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:6087]
 at main/previousButton_clickHandler()[C:\Data\dev\Flex\main\src\main.mxml:48]
 at main/__previousButton_click()[C:\Data\dev\Flex\main\src\main.mxml:241]
```

I experimented with adding and removing controls from the grid, and eventually narrowed it down to a a VGroup I've got in the grid.  If I remove that VGroup (and all it's children), the transition plays fine.  Add it back in, and everything blows up again.  I tried using a VBox instead of a VGroup, but there was no change--same error.  I also tried getting rid of horizontalAlign="center", and again, no change.

Some further experimenting reveals that if I only have one child in the VGroup, then the transition works.  As soon as I get two children in the VGroup, however, it throws the error.

Additionally, if I remove the VGroup completely and simply make the Labels direct children of the GridItem, it fails (same Invalid BitmapData error).  So it seems that perhaps the real culprit is having multiple controls at the same level in the control tree?  E.g., two controls work if they are in a linear parent-child relationship inside the GridItem (GridItem->VGroup->Label), but two labels at the same level (whether their immediate parent is the VGroup or the GridItem) causes the Invalid BitmapData error.

I'm unaware of any other control I could use to accomplish what I'm trying to do with the Grid control, which is layout things in a table, with some cells that span into other rows or columns.  TileLayout would work if I didn't need to span into other rows and columns in a few cases.

I've thought about using absolute positioning, but that will make it difficult (impossible?) to easily add/remove other controls into the "grid," which is what I want to do.  When we're running subscription promotionals, we'll add text into certain cells noting how the promotional affects (or does not affect) that particular pricing option.

Suggestions?

Here's what the grid looks like.

```
<mx:Grid id='membershipGrid' >
 <mx:GridRow>
      <mx:GridItem>

      </mx:GridItem>
      <mx:GridItem>
           <s:Label text="One Year" fontWeight="bold"/>
      </mx:GridItem>
      <mx:GridItem>
           <s:Label text="Two Year" fontWeight="bold"/>
      </mx:GridItem>
      <mx:GridItem>
           <s:Label text="5 Year" fontWeight="bold"/>
      </mx:GridItem>
      <mx:GridItem>
           <!-- Comment out this VGroup, and everything works fine -->
           <s:VGroup horizontalAlign="center">
                <s:Label text="Monthly Autorenew"  fontWeight="bold"/>
                <s:Label text="Payment plan option is not available" fontStyle="italic" />
                <s:Label text="for multiple year memberhips." fontStyle="italic" />
           </s:VGroup>
      </mx:GridItem>
 </mx:GridRow>
 <mx:GridRow>
      <mx:GridItem>
           <s:Label text="Standard Membership" />
      </mx:GridItem>
      <mx:GridItem>
           <s:RadioButton id="standardOneYear" group="{membershipTypeSelection}"
                             label="{pricing.getMembership(MembershipName.STANDARD_ONE_YEAR).currencyPrice}" />

      </mx:GridItem>
      <mx:GridItem>
           <s:RadioButton id="standardTwoYear" group="{membershipTypeSelection}"
                             label="{pricing.getMembership(MembershipName.STANDARD_TWO_YEAR).currencyPrice}" />

      </mx:GridItem>
      <mx:GridItem>
           <s:RadioButton id="standardFiveYear" group="{membershipTypeSelection}"
                             label="{pricing.getMembership(MembershipName.STANDARD_FIVE_YEAR).currencyPrice}" />

      </mx:GridItem>
      <mx:GridItem horizontalAlign="center">
           <s:RadioButton id="monthlyAutorenew" group="{membershipTypeSelection}"
                             label="{pricing.getMembership(MembershipName.MONTHLY_AUTORENEW).currencyPrice}" />

      </mx:GridItem>
 </mx:GridRow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: don't use a Spark transition.  I had to give up.  Bummer, huh?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but when I was facing similar issues trying to get a Spark Wipe effect to work as a transition I had to use a MX:Box component as a container for the Spark Group containers so that it would work. These Spark transitions seem to be very temperamental.